# Why the "if else statement" is not working properly?

Tags: javascript

I am doing JS Algorithms and Data structures projects in freecodecamp and I am stuck at the last problem "Cash register". I already did some of the coding and my code doesn't pass all the tests.

The link to the problem : https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures-projects/cash-register

My code doesn't pass the 3 and 5 number test. In number 3, the output is almost the same, but the last part ["PENNY",0.03], which doesn't match with the output. In number 5, the `totalCid` and `cashback` variables are equal but it doesn't return "CLOSED". If those are equal it should return the status "CLOSED".

```js
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  var cashback = (cash - price)
  var returnMoney = {
    status: "",
    change: []
  }
  var totalCid = cid.map(v => {
      return v[1]
    })
    .reduce((a, b) => {
      return a + b
    })
    .toFixed(2)
  console.log(cashback)
  console.log(totalCid)
  if (totalCid === cashback) {
    returnMoney.status = "CLOSED"
    returnMoney.change = cid
    return returnMoney
  } else if (totalCid < cashback) {
    returnMoney.status = "INSUFFICIENT_FUND"
    returnMoney.change = []
    return returnMoney
  } else {
    var denomValue = [{
        bill: "ONE HUNDRED",
        val: 100
      },
      {
        bill: "TWENTY",
        val: 20
      },
      {
        bill: "TEN",
        val: 10
      },
      {
        bill: "FIVE",
        val: 5
      },
      {
        bill: "ONE",
        val: 1
      },
      {
        bill: "QUARTER",
        val: 0.25
      },
      {
        bill: "DIME",
        val: 0.10
      },
      {
        bill: "NICKEL",
        val: 0.05
      },
      {
        bill: "PENNY",
        val: 0.01
      }
    ]
    var newCidArray = [];
    var currVal = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < denomValue.length; i++) {
      while (cashback >= denomValue[i].val && currVal < cid[8 - i][1]) {
        cashback -= denomValue[i].val.toFixed(2);
        currVal += denomValue[i].val;
      }

      if (currVal > 0) {
        newCidArray.push([denomValue[i].bill, currVal]);
      }
      currVal = 0; // reset current value (currVal) to zero after the loop has completed
    }
    returnMoney.status = "OPEN"
    returnMoney.change = newCidArray
    return returnMoney

  }

}
console.log(checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [
  ["PENNY", 0.5],
  ["NICKEL", 0],
  ["DIME", 0],
  ["QUARTER", 0],
  ["ONE", 0],
  ["FIVE", 0],
  ["TEN", 0],
  ["TWENTY", 0],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]
]))
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Cash Register" in JavaScript. You should change your title to reflect the actual coding problem you have. It is very unlikely someone would come here and search on "Cash Register Return Issue" when they are having a problem.

Comment: okay changed my question. Thanks for your suggestion. It is my first post here.

Comment: `.toFixed(2)` converts a number to a string, and so when you do `===` comparisons later on, they will all evaluate as `false` (not equal). Because a string is never strictly equal to a number.

Comment: @trincot thanks for the help! really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a total of 3 problems in your code.

The first has been pointed out by @trincot: `toFixed()` returns a string, which you cannot compare with `===` to a number.

The second is that even if the cash in the drawer is more than the expected change, you can be in an `INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS` situation because you cannot split the bills (notes, in British English) and coins you have. This means that at the end of your algorithm you must check whether the change sums up.

The third, and major one, comes from working with floating point numbers. If you click on "Run code snippet under your code" you can see that the change would be `0.49000000000000027` dollars in pennies.

The only safe way out of the swamp of floating point is to convert everything to integers. So what I did, apart from fixing the first two problems, is convert dollars to pennies in your script. I tried not to alter your script too much, nonetheless.

```javascript
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  // P stands for pennies
  var cidP = cid.map(v => [v[0], Math.round(v[1] * 100)])
  var priceP = Math.round(price * 100)
  var cashP  = Math.round(cash * 100)
  var cashbackP = (cashP - priceP)
  var returnMoney = {
    status: "",
    change: []
  }
  var totalCidP = cidP.map(v => {
      return v[1]
    })
    .reduce((a, b) => {
      return a + b
    })
  if (totalCidP === cashbackP) {
    returnMoney.status = "CLOSED"
    returnMoney.change = cid
    return returnMoney
  } else if (totalCidP < cashbackP) {
    returnMoney.status = "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS"
    returnMoney.change = []
    return returnMoney
  } else {
    var denomValueP = [
      {bill: "ONE HUNDRED", val: 10000},
      {bill: "TWENTY", val: 2000},
      {bill: "TEN", val: 1000},
      {bill: "FIVE", val: 500},
      {bill: "ONE", val: 100},
      {bill: "QUARTER", val: 25},
      {bill: "DIME", val: 10},
      {bill: "NICKEL", val: 5},
      {bill: "PENNY", val: 1}
    ]
    var changeArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < denomValueP.length; i++) {
      var currValP = 0;
      while (cashbackP >= denomValueP[i].val && currValP < cidP[8 - i][1]) {
        cashbackP -= denomValueP[i].val;
        currValP  += denomValueP[i].val;
      }
      if (currValP > 0) {
        changeArray.push([denomValueP[i].bill, currValP / 100]);
      }
    }
    if (cashbackP === 0) {
      returnMoney.status = "OPEN"
      returnMoney.change = changeArray
    } else {
      returnMoney.status = "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS"
      returnMoney.change = []
    }
    return returnMoney
  }
}
```

As to why those `Math.round()` are needed, try this:

```javascript
4567.89 * 100 === 456789  // => false
```

**EDIT**

You asked for clarification about the last if-else in the code. The fourth paragraph in [freecodecamp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures-projects/cash-register) says:

> Return `{status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS", change: []}` if cash-in-drawer
>   is less than the change due, **or if you cannot return the exact
>   change**.

If you got to the end of the algorithm and `cashbackP`, which you have been decreasing for every bill or coin you added to the change, has not gone to zero, this means that the change is not complete, and you are in the situation I emphasized.

Comment: thanks for the help @Walter. But I did not understood the last if else condition. 
```
 if (cashbackP === 0) {
      returnMoney.status = "OPEN"
      returnMoney.change = changeArray
    } else {
      returnMoney.status = "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS"
      returnMoney.change = []
    }
```
could you please explain it?

Comment: Hi, I added an explanation at the bottom of my answer, I hope it will clear your doubts. I see you are new to StackOverflow, so let me remind you that upvoting useful answers, not only accepting them, is important for the good functioning of StackOverflow ;-)

Comment: Actually i upvoted your answer but as I am new it doesn't show. So sorry about that. And thanks for the help. Appreciate it.